# Using a texture mask to change color of 3D mesh

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm a 3D artist trying to help out a client so my knowledge of the code is very limited, however, he's trying make a texture mask drive the color of some shoe laces so that a user can personalize to his liking.

[image]

Since I'm a 3D artist and don't have access to the code, here's how it works in blender.

The mask driving the color is on the top left. I'm changing the color of the shoe laces model shown on the right through the color wheel on the bottom left. **The white squares on the shoe laces have to stay white, hence why I'm using a mask in blender**.

If anyone knows a generalized solution that works on most cases it'd be really appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's quite a comprehensive question, there are several ways to go about it. Below is an example with a native object and a commented model, which could be your shoelaces, exported from, for example, Blender (You can take similar steps for the mapped texture.).

You can of course also do this in R3F, here is one of the official examples:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/shoe-configurator-qxjoj?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.161.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.161.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<canvas class="webglHH"> </canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.webglHH");

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = 5;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
renderer.setClearColor(0x1e0029);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(ambientLight);
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(directionalLight);

//-------Primitive

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  roughness: 0.4,
  metalness: 0.6,
});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.x = -1.5;
cube.scale.set(2, 2, 2)
scene.add(cube);

// -------GLB

// const loader = new GLTFLoader();
// let shoe;

// loader.load("REACT.glb", function (gltf) {
//   shoe = gltf.scene;
//   shoe.position.set(0, 0, 2);
//   shoe.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
//   scene.add(shoe);
// });

// function onColorChanged2(event) {
//   const colorHex = event.target.value;
//   shoe.traverse((child) => {
//     if (child.isMesh) {
//       child.material.color.set(colorHex);
//     }
//   });
// }

//-------picker

function onColorChanged(event) {
  const colorHex = event.target.value;
  cube.material.color.set(colorHex);
}

const colorPicker = document.createElement("input");
colorPicker.type = "color";
colorPicker.style.position = "absolute";
colorPicker.style.top = "44%";
colorPicker.style.left = "55%";
colorPicker.style.width = "100px";
colorPicker.style.height = "70px";
colorPicker.style.borderRadius = "50%";
document.body.appendChild(colorPicker);

// function onColorChanged - primitive, onColorChanged2 - GLB
colorPicker.addEventListener("input", onColorChanged);

function onWR() {
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;
  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", onWR);
onWR();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
</script>
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but there doesn't seem to be a mask here. I should've been more clear on the question, but the white squares on the laces don't change color when selecting the color on the color picker, even though it's the same geometry. Edited the original question for more clarity!

Comment: @Wrothtyr Procedural Nodes + Three.js is a more complex topic. Generally, we remain a bit speculative if _"...don't have access to the code..."._ Generally Three.js loads the model and putting texture to it, then you can use the color picker... After exporting the texture from Blender, it is quasi-baked _per se_ or on a mesh, like any other image. If, for example, you have a shoe, and you export it and this shoe has other meshes, like the laces, you can grab them directly using `getObjectByName`, and you can manipulate them separately, putting materials etc. I hope we have common context...

Comment: I'm not using anything procedural, textures were made in photoshop and substance painter. Not sure if by procedural you mean mathematically generated such as noise